# How to resolve --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. on laradock mysql container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laradock

I'm using laradock.
when I use `docker-compose up mysql`
I got this error.

```
mysql_1                | Initializing database
mysql_1                | 2018-04-22T10:41:01.362165Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
mysql_1                | 2018-04-22T10:41:01.362585Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
mysql_1                |
laradock_mysql_1 exited with code 1
```

I tried to add this setting on laradock/mysql/Dockerfile like this

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION=latest
FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

#####################################
# Set Timezone
#####################################

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

CMD ["mysqld --ignore-db-dir=lost+found"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

but, I'm still getting above error.
Do you have any idea on this solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Actually, adding `--ignore-db-dir` was a very good idea. There is just a tiny error in the CMD format. It should be: `CMD ["mysqld", "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In order to solve it, you have to

1. go to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`
2. you will find a folder named `data`. rename it into `data1`.
3. launch command prompt as an administrator.
4. execute `mysqld --initialize-insecure`.
5. go to the services in the control panel, stop all services related to MySql such as `MySQL57`.
6. Start `MySQL`

Comment: I did a `reinstall all the services` from the WAMP tray ==> Tools and now it's running fine